# Python/Numpy optimisation

Tags: python, numpy, micro-optimization

I have a simple python class which is approx 40 lines of calculations, given thereafter with a use case exemple, that perform a simple computation (independence testing based on L2 distance between densities), and it takes a lot of time to compute with only 100 points and 100 boostrap. Here is the code and some data to test it :

```py
import numpy as np

class IndependenceTesting:


    def __init__(self,data,a,b,dim_to_test,number_of_simulation = 1000):

        # rescale the data :
        self.i = dim_to_test
        self.data = (data - a)/(b-a)
        self.d = self.data.shape[1]
        self.n = self.data.shape[0]
        self.N = number_of_simulation

        self.data_restricted = np.hstack((self.data[:,:(self.i-1)],self.data[:,(self.i+1):]))
        self.emp_cop_restricted = np.array([np.mean(np.array([np.sum(dat <= u) for dat in self.data_restricted]) == self.d - 1) for u in self.data_restricted])

    def simulated_dataset(self):
        unif = np.random.uniform(size=(self.n,1))
        before = [x for x in range(self.d) if x < self.i]
        after = [x for x in range(self.d) if x > self.i]
        return np.hstack((self.data[:,before],unif,self.data[:,after]))

    def mse(self, data):
        emp_cop = np.array([np.mean(np.array([np.sum(dat <= u) for dat in data]) == self.d) for u in self.data])
        return ((emp_cop - self.emp_cop_restricted)**2).mean()

    def mse_distribution(self):
        return np.array([self.mse(self.simulated_dataset()) for i in np.arange(self.N)])

    def mse_observed(self):
        return self.mse(self.data)

    def quantile(self):
        return np.mean(self.mse_distribution() < self.mse_observed())

    def p_value(self):
        return 1 - self.quantile()

# clayton copula exemple
points = np.array([[0.56129339, 0.99710045, 0.57646982],
       [0.12256328, 0.17201513, 0.12885428],
       [0.08511945, 0.11828913, 0.10965346],
       [0.98324131, 0.95728269, 0.92776529],
       [0.54921155, 0.39785825, 0.31361901],
       [0.99487892, 0.63916092, 0.79895483],
       [0.50433754, 0.56999504, 0.60091257],
       [0.92823054, 0.93214344, 0.89725172],
       [0.17751366, 0.18346635, 0.20097246],
       [0.51466364, 0.63436169, 0.46611089],
       [0.25800664, 0.28831929, 0.2903953 ],
       [0.20481173, 0.15871781, 0.15857803],
       [0.31187595, 0.24635342, 0.24171054],
       [0.93662273, 0.80126302, 0.90160681],
       [0.34507788, 0.28888433, 0.30064778],
       [0.81832302, 0.84296836, 0.73139211],
       [0.90751759, 0.74184158, 0.60553314],
       [0.38432821, 0.28571601, 0.22660958],
       [0.47439066, 0.71614234, 0.54718021],
       [0.19106315, 0.31102177, 0.18200903],
       [0.38445433, 0.53108707, 0.35387428],
       [0.77625631, 0.98215295, 0.7751224 ],
       [0.52178207, 0.60999481, 0.45028018],
       [0.2446548 , 0.22270593, 0.30778265],
       [0.62656838, 0.68516045, 0.49434858],
       [0.04573006, 0.03194788, 0.04361497],
       [0.09852491, 0.09004012, 0.08412001],
       [0.11361961, 0.10879038, 0.11352351],
       [0.86116076, 0.92607349, 0.98481143],
       [0.47235565, 0.89094039, 0.52014104],
       [0.32994434, 0.38757998, 0.48919507],
       [0.0052988 , 0.00701797, 0.00637456],
       [0.6230293 , 0.48457337, 0.73184841],
       [0.8039672 , 0.78400854, 0.76272398],
       [0.4585257 , 0.64504907, 0.42333538],
       [0.86565877, 0.89902376, 0.75903263],
       [0.96763817, 0.883972  , 0.99965508],
       [0.72431971, 0.86391135, 0.73501178],
       [0.99153281, 0.98536847, 0.93416086],
       [0.11746542, 0.1142617 , 0.09463402],
       [0.86322008, 0.79150614, 0.48112103],
       [0.031247  , 0.03196072, 0.02701867],
       [0.44120581, 0.48729271, 0.4607829 ],
       [0.01393345, 0.01400763, 0.01567294],
       [0.24365903, 0.20966226, 0.218757  ],
       [0.94584172, 0.94507558, 0.98623726],
       [0.79201305, 0.65503713, 0.79137242],
       [0.06040952, 0.04573984, 0.04640926],
       [0.5673345 , 0.27567432, 0.35234249],
       [0.15860006, 0.12212839, 0.15206467],
       [0.00826576, 0.00407989, 0.00479213],
       [0.72549979, 0.70557491, 0.60543315],
       [0.83039818, 0.76500639, 0.89549151],
       [0.6844257 , 0.81317716, 0.74480599],
       [0.36904583, 0.41081094, 0.36072341],
       [0.14211919, 0.14508685, 0.11253501],
       [0.85139993, 0.86351303, 0.9571894 ],
       [0.72638876, 0.92343587, 0.67884759],
       [0.26816568, 0.22169953, 0.28666315],
       [0.04672121, 0.06183976, 0.09154045],
       [0.81235354, 0.61478793, 0.76379907],
       [0.3562006 , 0.2863009 , 0.31200338],
       [0.42761726, 0.40890689, 0.53401233],
       [0.66337324, 0.96621491, 0.86041736],
       [0.55199335, 0.49320256, 0.43633604],
       [0.80474216, 0.72338883, 0.80206245],
       [0.10724037, 0.11511572, 0.09207419],
       [0.36170945, 0.21664901, 0.20827803],
       [0.9831956 , 0.93518925, 0.89061586],
       [0.10740562, 0.10503344, 0.12320474],
       [0.67589713, 0.65032996, 0.69570242],
       [0.07020206, 0.04963921, 0.06650148],
       [0.4841555 , 0.68809898, 0.65333047],
       [0.60416479, 0.74849448, 0.90509825],
       [0.59250114, 0.71818894, 0.52021291],
       [0.64724464, 0.91296217, 0.96050912],
       [0.75206371, 0.83658298, 0.74361849],
       [0.7338096 , 0.58894243, 0.68243507],
       [0.63778258, 0.79158918, 0.69136578],
       [0.73200902, 0.91405125, 0.81908408],
       [0.15349378, 0.19096759, 0.18099441],
       [0.53616182, 0.51364115, 0.49836299],
       [0.60663723, 0.66756579, 0.66600087],
       [0.72565001, 0.84115262, 0.76362573],
       [0.65200849, 0.86601501, 0.80996763],
       [0.02593363, 0.03604641, 0.05726403],
       [0.39141485, 0.31616432, 0.36365569],
       [0.64372213, 0.53823589, 0.88647631],
       [0.79079997, 0.74427728, 0.67554193],
       [0.07105107, 0.08504079, 0.09113675],
       [0.82765688, 0.7680246 , 0.93645974],
       [0.42258547, 0.46685121, 0.46316008],
       [0.08749291, 0.09122353, 0.10884091],
       [0.93644383, 0.81629942, 0.70997887],
       [0.92635455, 0.95107457, 0.99150588],
       [0.05725108, 0.03565845, 0.03288627],
       [0.11064689, 0.11070949, 0.11499569],
       [0.93098314, 0.98552576, 0.93522353],
       [0.91617665, 0.8137873 , 0.71928403],
       [0.93477362, 0.87389527, 0.87646188]])
points[:,2] = 1 - points[:,2]
points = np.concatenate((points,np.array(np.random.uniform(size=points.shape[0])).reshape((points.shape[0],1))),axis=1)


p_values = [IndependenceTesting(points,np.repeat(0,4),np.repeat(1,4),dim_to_test = i,number_of_simulation= 100).p_value() for i in np.arange(points.shape[1])]

print(p_values)
```

The line that takes the most evaluation time is probably the computation of `emp_cop` in the `mse` function.

Do you think this code can be optimised ? I'm fairly new to python.

Thanks !

Answer (score 2):

Generally, list comprehensions in python are slow and [broadcasting](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.broadcasting.html) is much more efficient. In your specific case, `np.array([np.sum(dat <= u) for dat in data])` takes a lot of time and can be replaced by `np.sum(data <= u, axis=1)`. In my experiments, that gives a significant speed up. You can likely further improve the performance by replacing additional list comprehensions with broadcast statements.

```
# Before
6.9 s ± 103 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
# After
289 ms ± 19.6 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

Answer (score 2):

I made a solution using numba as well as broadcasting as mentioned in another answer. The code had to be restructured slightly. Whether numba is faster depends on the exact number of experiments and shape of `data`. I also made a variant that uses a slightly different broadcasting approach not supported by numba (coined advanced as it vectorizes the double loop, rather than a single loop). Three methods are usable from the 'method' keyword.

```
import numpy as np
import numba

@numba.njit(fastmath=True)
def emp_cop_numba(data, self_data, shape):
    emp_cop = np.zeros(shape[0])
    for i in range(shape[0]):
        u = self_data[i]
        emp_cop[i] = np.mean(np.sum(data <= u, axis=1) == shape[1])
        i += 1
    return emp_cop

def emp_cop_simple_broadcasting(data, self_data, shape):
    emp_cop = np.zeros(shape[0])
    for i, u in enumerate(self_data):
        emp_cop[i] = np.mean(np.sum(data <= u, axis=1) == shape[1])
    return emp_cop

def emp_cop_advanced_broadcasting(data, self_data, shape):
    emp_cop = np.mean(np.sum(data[None,:,:] <= self_data[:,None,:], axis=2) == shape[1], axis=1)
    return emp_cop

class IndependenceTesting:
    def __init__(self, data, a, b, dim_to_test, number_of_simulation=1000, method='numba'):
        # rescale the data :
        self.i = dim_to_test
        self.data = (data - a)/(b-a)
        self.d = self.data.shape[1]
        self.n = self.data.shape[0]
        self.N = number_of_simulation
        self.method = method

        self.data_restricted = np.hstack((self.data[:,:(self.i - 1)], self.data[:,(self.i + 1):]))
        self.emp_cop_restricted = np.array([np.mean(np.array([np.sum(dat <= u) for dat in self.data_restricted]) == self.d - 1) for u in self.data_restricted])

    def simulated_dataset(self):
        unif = np.random.uniform(size=(self.n,1))
        before = [x for x in range(self.d) if x < self.i] 
        after = [x for x in range(self.d) if x > self.i]
        return np.hstack((self.data[:,before],unif,self.data[:,after]))

    def mse(self, data):
        if self.method == 'numba':
            emp_cop = emp_cop_numba(data, self.data, self.data.shape)
        elif self.method == 'simple_broadcasting':
            emp_cop = emp_cop_simple_broadcasting(data, self.data, self.data.shape)
        elif self.method == 'advanced_broadcasting':
            emp_cop = emp_cop_advanced_broadcasting(data, self.data, self.data.shape)

        return ((emp_cop - self.emp_cop_restricted)**2).mean()

    def mse_distribution(self):
        return np.array([self.mse(self.simulated_dataset()) for i in np.arange(self.N)])

    def mse_observed(self):
        return self.mse(self.data)

    def quantile(self):
        return np.mean(self.mse_distribution() < self.mse_observed())

    def p_value(self):
        return 1 - self.quantile()

np.random.seed(42)
points = np.random.random((100,3))
points[:,2] = 1 - points[:,2]
points = np.concatenate((points,np.array(np.random.uniform(size=points.shape[0])).reshape((points.shape[0],1))),axis=1)

for method in ('numba', 'simple_broadcasting', 'advanced_broadcasting'):
    np.random.seed(42)
    p_values = [IndependenceTesting(points,np.repeat(0,4),np.repeat(1,4),dim_to_test = i,number_of_simulation=100, method=method).p_value() for i in np.arange(points.shape[1])]
    print(p_values)
```

With 1000 simulations and data of shape (1000,3), the timings (for the emp_cop_X calls) are

```
%timeit emp_cop_numba(data, self_data, shape)
11.1 ms ± 517 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)

%timeit emp_cop_simple_broadcasting(data, self_data, shape, emp_cop_restricted)
57.7 ms ± 441 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)

%timeit emp_cop_advanced_broadcasting(data, self_data, shape, emp_cop_restricted)
41.6 ms ± 552 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a comment to @user2653663 Numba approach. If you want to use Numba really efficiently it is recommendable to write simple loops, whereas in Numpy you would try to avoid any explicit loop.

**Example**

```
import numba as nb
import numpy as np

@numba.njit(parallel=True)
def emp_cop_numba_2(data):
    emp_cop=np.empty(data.shape[0])

    for i in numba.prange(data.shape[0]):
        count_2=0
        for j in range(data.shape[0]):
            count=0
            for k in range(data.shape[1]):
                if data[j,k]<=data[i,k]:
                    count+=1
            if count==data.shape[1]:
                count_2+=1
        emp_cop[i]=count_2/data.shape[0]
    return emp_cop
```

**Timings**

```
points=np.random.rand(1000,3)

#user2653663
%timeit res1=emp_cop_numba(points, points, points.shape)
#7.73 ms ± 69.5 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)

#parallel=False, faster for very small arrays, but slower for larger ones
%timeit res2=emp_cop_numba_2(points)
#2.56 ms ± 36.2 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)

#parallel=True
%timeit res=emp_cop_numba_2(points)
#487 µs ± 21.2 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think hstack cause decay in the performance of your code, If you have few point, test np.delete(data, 0, i) instead.

Comment: according to `cProfile` it is the list comprehension in `mse` that is the problem, not the `hstack`.